# Change the message of a ProgressDialog in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog running in a AsyncTask.
I`m trying to achive that as soon as the Length of a buffer is bigger then lets say 10000, the message from the ProgressDialog changes.

Can somebody help me please, is this possible?
Thank you in advance.

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progUpdate) { 
         if (progUpdate[0] >= 10000){ 
            progress.setMessage("Informatie wordt opgehaald...."); 
        } 
     }
```

The buffer is created in a AsyncTask doInBackGround:

```
try { 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); 

        System.out.println("Response: " + response.getEntity().getContentLength());

        /******* READ CONTENT IN BUFFER *******/
        InputStream inputStreamActivity = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamActivity));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        int count = sb.length();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
             publishProgress(sb.length());

        }

        /******* CLOSE CONNECTION AND STREAM *******/
        System.out.println(sb);
        inputStreamActivity.close();
        kpn = sb.toString();

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change your dialog's message, you'll want to use the onProgressUpdate method of the AsyncTask and define the 2nd paramater of your AsyncTask as an Integer.  The onProgressUpdate will look something like:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progUpdate) {
     if (progUpdate[0] >= 10000){  // change the 10000 to whatever
        progress.setMessage("The new message");
    }
 }
```

To call this, you'll want to update these lines in your doInBackground method of your AsyncTask:

```
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        publishProgress(sb.length());
    }
```

And get rid of that Runnable.  You don't need it.   Take a look at the official android documentation for AsyncTask here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html   There's a great example for you on that page.

Comment: Hi SBerg413,
Thx for replying, i changed the code (edited) but it does not seem to change the message.
Could you have a short look please?

Comment: NOt sure what you were doing with that for loop but wasn't doing anything.  I removed it and added the publishProgress call to your while loop.  Take a look.